# download an existing file using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, force-download

I'm trying to make a website that can download jpg,png,pdf,docx file those are uploaded by an admin.

uploading those content is working without problem. when uploading i insert that file name in to mysql table as well. using that table I'am showing the uploaded file names to users.

this is the code I'am using for display those files.

```
<?php
            if (!empty($downloads)) {
                foreach ($downloads as $val) {
                    ?>            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-danger">
                            <div class="panel-heading panel-title">
                                <?php echo $val['upload_description']; ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <?php echo $val['file_name']; ?>
                                <div class="clear-fix clear clearfix"></div>
                                <div id="download" onclick="downloadFile('<?php echo $val['file_name']; ?>');" class="btn btn-danger">Download</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

and this is my ajax code

```
function downloadFile(str) {
                        //alert(str);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'downloadfiles',
                            data: {value: str},
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert('ok' + data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

when some one click on the download button, using ajax and jquery I'am sending that file name to a download_controller. 
this is the function in the download_controller file

```
public function download_files() {
    $fileName = $this->input->post('value');
    $file_path = 'uploaded/' . $fileName;
    $this->_push_file($file_path, $fileName);
 }

function _push_file($path, $name) {
        $this->load->helper('download');
        // make sure it's a file before doing anything!
        if (is_file($path)) {
            // required for IE
            if (ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) {
                ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
            }

            // get the file mime type using the file extension
            $this->load->helper('file');
            $mime = get_mime_by_extension($path);
            // Build the headers to push out the file properly.
            header('Pragma: public');     // required
            header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)) . ' GMT');
            header('Cache-Control: private', false);
            header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);  // Add the mime type from Code igniter.
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($name) . '"');  // Add the file name
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path)); // provide file size
            header('Connection: close');
            readfile($path); // push it out
            exit();
        }
    }
```

but the downloading never starting. when trying to download a png file i'm getting this kind of message.

[image]

can some one tell me what is the wrong thing I'am doing here?

thank You

Comment: Do you have to download the file through Ajax? if you set the link to `downloadfiles` url, it will download the file and stay on the same page.

Comment: did you try force_download?

Comment: @KraneBird - can you please give me the right way to do this? still I couldn't make it right

thank You

Comment: @kumar_v -  yes I did. but the same thing happen.

Comment: Try using `header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');` instead of `header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);`

Comment: @ailvenge -  still the same happening.

Comment: Damn. You got to add `ob_clean();` before `readfile()`.

Comment: @ElefantPhace - I didn't went for any classes or any institute for learn php every thing was self learnt. so there could be bad syntaxes and errors. if you can give me the best way to do that without braking php code it will be helpful to me. 

thank you.

Comment: @ailvenge - still the same boss. :(

Comment: @ElefantPhace - if you don't now the answers please don't comment to questions. there are lot of people who like to help others except you.
Thanks.

Comment: You're right. But why do you think no one has given you answer?

Comment: @ElefantPhace - every one comment here was tried to give me some help. I think you will also trying to help me. that is why I asked to correct me if i doing wrong thing. any way using those comments i could solve my problem. 
that means learning. 
every one can't do every thing on there own. we humans need help from others. we are not gods. 

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found what I did wrong. thanks to Mr.KraneBird

I change my ajax code from this

```
$.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'downloadfiles',
                            data: {value: str},
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert('ok' + data);
                            }
                        });
```

to this.

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url().'downloadfiles/'?>" + str;
```

without posting it to the download_controller now i redirect to the download_controller.

now it is working well without any error.

thank you every one who waste your valuable time to help me.

Comment: you could make it more user-friendly by ajax itself..I mean without redirecting..

You could have to give the exact path of your controller file like 

url: '<?=base_url('directory_name/controller_name');?>'..

Just try it yaar..